# How to forward output from CMake execute_process to CMake's logs?

Tags: cmake, cmake-language

In my CMake file, I set up a Python test environment:

```cmake
execute_process(
  COMMAND pip install -U -r ${REQUIREMENTS}
  RESULT_VARIABLE STATUS
)
```

The issue is, I usually don't need its verbose `OUTPUT`. So I want to optionally hide it. This is what I've done:

```cmake
if(SHOW_PIP_LOGS)
  execute_process(...)
else()
  execute_process(... OUTPUT_QUIET)
endif()
```

The thing is, there is already a way to control what logs are shown in CMake: it's `--log-level` coupled with `message()`. This way I don't need to manage any logging-related variables. But the command outputs directly to stdout, without going through CMake log system.

Can I somehow forward the output of a command invocation to CMake's logs?

The output must be printed on-line, without buffering everything to a variable first, so that if a `pip` takes a long time installing packages, I can see what's going on.

Comment: It seems that if this feature is implemented, I'll be able to conditionally enable `OUTPUT_QUIET` based on the log level: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22627

Comment: How about usiing `OUTPUT_VARIABLE` of `execute_process` with standard `message`?

Comment: @ixSci That works, but now the output is buffered and not printed interactively